# Why Python web application throwing *AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Div'*?

Tags: python

I am building a python web application to show a gold price movement in a time series graph. But my code is throwing an error saying,

app.layout = html.Div([
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Div'

This is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input,Output

from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

url = "http://goldpricez.com/gold/history/lkr/years-3"

req = Request(url=url)
html = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')
df = pd.read_html(url)  # this will give you a list of dataframes from html

df1 = df[3]

first_val = df1.iloc[0][0]


date = df1[0]
price = df1[1]

data = [df1[0],df1[1]]

headers = ["Date", "Price"]

df3 = pd.concat(data, axis=1, keys=headers)


from datetime import datetime
df3['Date'] = df3['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y'))


df3['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['Date']).year
df3['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['Date']).month
df3['Day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['Date']).day

df3['WDay'] = df3['Date'].dt.dayofweek

df3['WeekDayName'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['Date']).day_name()



print(df3['WDay'])



writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()


app = dash.Dash(__name__)



app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1("Gold Price Analyst" , style={'text-align' : 'center'}),

    dcc.Graph(id='this_year_graph', figure={})


])

@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='this_year_graph', component_property='figure')]
)

def update_graph():

    dff = df3.copy()
    dff = [df4['Date'],df4['Price']]

    fig = px.line(dff , x=dff['Date'], y=dff['Price'])

    return fig

if __name__ =='__main__' :
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Here I have added *html = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')* this as well. I am new to python and need help to solve this.

Comment: The line you added cause the problem. You imported dash_html_components as html. Then you reassigned it to text output with that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign to html,

`html = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')`

you overwrite the html import that has same name,

`import dash_html_components as html`

Try to rename that html variable to something else like, `html_content`,

`html_content = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')`